# Address Card and ID Card are not working in font awesome

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

I am using id-card icon of font awesome.

```
<i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>
```

The icon is even listed on Font Awesome's Official Website but still doesn't seem to work, it just shows the blank box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referencing locally and not using their CDN.

Check to ensure you have version 4.7 of Font Awesome referenced in your code. Those icons are new to that version.

Comment: Thank you Frank version was only the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the address card icon.
`&#xf2c3;`

Above code is work in font awesome 4.7.0 css